# Where to store authentication token in SPA

Tags: php, vue.js, authentication, single-page-application

Okay, so I'm working on a single page application that grabs data from a back-end API which I also design.
The current workflow of authentication is like this :
Users send an HTTP Post request to the server containing a username and password.
The backend API checks the information and if the fields are valid it generates a token.
SPA receives the token and stores it inside localstorage for future usage.
Next to API requests will use the token inside localstorage and will be sent with an authorization header containing the token.
My questions are :
1.Is this safe? and if not why?
2.Is it better to use cookies instead of local storage ? and why?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using of cookies is more secure than localStorage because of `Secure` (https only) and `HttpOnly` (server access only) attributes. This approach is better described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Restrict_access_to_cookies